# Trouble receiving data from React to Update a Mongo collection using python REST API via Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, mongodb, rest, flask

From a React front end I'm supposed to receive a request in form of two arguments(id,tags). 'id' would be the mongoose 'id' to locate a particular entry in the collection in MongoDB.
Now, "tags" is an array which is going to update the tag column in the Mongo collection named "table1" using the request 'id'. I'm using the following code to receive request and update the
same in MongoDB using a Flask_REST API (python/flask) but not working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask import request

@app.route('/update_tag/<id>/', methods=['PUT'])
def update_tag(id):
    picture = request_json()

    client = MongoClient(
        '11.111.111.11',
        username='Database_user',
        password='******',
        authSource='Database',
        authMechanism='HHA-HHA-111'
    )

    db_data1 = client.Database
    table1 = db_data1.table1
    table1.update({'_id':id}, {$set:{'_id': picture['tags']}})
```